# Color responsive patterns in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, patterns, fill

When using the Bucket Fill tool in GIMP, is it possible to create a custom pattern which will be responsive to the current color choice the way a custom brush (when made correctly) will respond to the color choice when using the Pencil tool?  If so, how?

If this is not possible, what would the simplest set of operations which would produce the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a lot on the pattern...

- If the pattern has transparency and you only want to change the color of the non-transparent parts, then bucket-fill the pattern on a transparent layer, lock the alpha (checkerboard icon in the Lock line at top of the Layers list) and bucket-fill with the required color.
- If the pattern is a color on black, then bucket-fill with a white-on-black pattern and then bucket-fill in `Multiply` mode with the color you want (`Darken only` is also a solution)
- If the pattern is a color on white, then bucket-fill with a black-on-white pattern and then bucket-fill in `Lighten only` mode with the color you want.

Comment: With just a minor change in my current workflow, your first solution works.  Now to set things up to optimize the new workflow.